# column to row conversion in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

hi i have a table like this

```
date         time    lot no   tester      result   sr1     sr2   sr3    
27/11/17     05:57     123     ABC         Pass     1       2     3    
27/11/17     05:57     123     ABC         Pass     4       5     6
27/11/17     05:57     123     ABC         fail     7       8     9
```

i need a result like this

```
date         time    lot no   tester      result      sr no
27/11/17     05:57     123     ABC         Pass     1
27/11/17     05:57     123     ABC         Pass     2
27/11/17     05:57     123     ABC         Pass     3
27/11/17     05:57     123     ABC         Pass     4
27/11/17     05:57     123     ABC         Pass     5
27/11/17     05:57     123     ABC         Pass     6
27/11/17     05:57     123     ABC         Fail     7
27/11/17     05:57     123     ABC         Fail     8
27/11/17     05:57     123     ABC         Fail     9
```

i need the query for the following table 
incase i didnt enter anything on the sr1,2 then it should not come in the below table and if the result is failed again its retested the result may come as "pass"

thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Refer this link. You will get some idea.  http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/UNPIVOT

Comment: In the desired output, you are losing information: you are still capturing the values 1, 2 and 3 for `sr_no` for the first row, say, but you can no longer tell which value was in column `sr1`, which was in column `sr2` and which was in column `sr3`. Is that OK for your needs?

Answer (score 1):

One simple method is `union all`:

```
select date, time, lotno, tester, result, sr1 as sr
from t
union all
select date, time, lotno, tester, result, sr2 as sr
from t
union all
select date, time, lotno, tester, result, sr3 as sr
from t;
```

There are other methods, if performance is a significant factor.  For all but very large tables, this should be fine.

Comment: yeah but i don't need duplicate values also if i need to retest the failure part and it should override as pass

Answer (score 0):

assuming your *table name* as `lot_tester`,

and *first column name* as `date_` instead of `date`( *intrusion of keyword* ), you may try this :

```
SQL> select *
       from
      (
        select date_, time, lotno , tester , result, sr_no 
          from lot_tester unpivot ( sr_no for sr in (sr1,sr2,sr3))
       )
       group by date_, time, lotno , tester , result, sr_no
       order by 6;
```

Comment: yeah but i don't need duplicate values also if i need to retest the failure part and it should override as pass